# Upon selecting a value from a drop down list, another drop list will generate on the same page

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

was wondering how can I create a sub drop down box upon selecting a value from the parent drop down box.

Example :

I ask the user to select "Which Page?" which in a form of a drop down box. The value are "About Us", "Products" and etc.

If the user selects "Products", I want another drop down box with value example "MP3", "IPHONE" and etc to appear below the first drop down box on the same page.

How can I do that? Advices please. Try searching on Google but not sure what to type in the search box.

Comment: try looking for javascript, php handles server side, and javascript client side activity.

Comment: .:try to use ajax and jquery? this is the best way i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this [tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/11/chained-ajax-selects-jquery/) may help you

Comment: is it possible for the outcome to be a couple of check box instead of constantly coming out a drop box? Example level 1 drop box -> level 2 drop box -> level 3 check boxes. Thankss

Comment: yes its possible you will need to modify script.js for that as per you requirement but i suggest you write your own javascript taking the logic from tutorial because modifying others script can sometime break it  and give unexpected result . secondly if you put checkbox it will break the visual appreance  because the script uses [chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) for themeing and chosen dosent work for checkboxes

Comment: Yea you are right, maybe I will try play around with the codes and see how it goes. Thanks ! do appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can always start looking on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp), this is a good way to start